# Real Face Recognition

Tags: android, opencv, face-detection, face-recognition

I am developing an Android app where I have to capture the real image of a person as soon as camera detected a face.
The challenge here is even a flat pic of any person is also detected as a face.
So just looking around a way to give a message to user that the pic is not a real person.

Tried looking some of the solutions like opencv and tensorflow but looks like there is no such way available where it can differentiate a real person vs image of a person using a single front camera or look for a way to differentiate between 3d face and flat face.

If anyone knows any solution where a real face can be differentiated from a image of a person, please let me know.

Comment: May I know the reason for downvote please?

Answer (score 1):

Unless the android phone has two rear-facing camera's. I don't see any way of distinguish 2d and 3d image.